# Data Archiving and moving to externals in salesforce

Tags: data-export

Just want to know about archiving data and moving to external source in SalesForce. I want to archive data and want to move it to external MS SQL source.

1. Is it possible?
2. Do I need any app for it?
3. Any process I can follow?

Comment: this question has been asked a lot -- see the Related questions on this page

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is it possible?

Yes, both with features offered by salesforce.com and external providers.

> 2. Do I need any app for it?

No, but you may find it less expensive to go with some other solution rather than salesforce.com's offerings.

> 3. Any process I can follow?

The official method of connecting with external systems is [Lightning Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=platform_connect_about.htm). Basically, you create an [OData](http://www.odata.org/) service on top of your MS SQL server, and you can then run reports, create list views, create and edit records, and so on, using External Objects. There is a cost for Lightning Connect (see your sales associate for details), but Lightning Connect uses *no* data on the salesforce.com servers, which allows you to free up your space for other data.

Other providers may provide offline storage or some other mechanism for storing records outside of salesforce.com that you can then integrate with. Consider checking out the [AppExchange](http://www.appexchange.com/) to see if anything there would suit your needs.

Comment: Do you think exporting the data and converting it all to a .sqlite file for use via DB Browser for SQLite is another good alternative here? Salesforce (fka Lightning) Connect is at least $4k per month, I believe for a single external connection. With .sqlite file you can see and edit the schema, which is kind of mirroring Salesforce Connect too.

Comment: @AndyHitchings It depends on your organization's needs for the data. It is *possible* that it may suit your needs, or it may not. The devil's in the details. I don't really know SQLite or DB Browser at all, and I don't know what your needs are, so my best answer is an emphatic maybe. You might be able to save yourself some time if you ask a new question, include as many details as possible, and allow us a chance to answer your question(s) in better detail.

Comment: Thanks. I asked this question here but I appreciate it's quite broad. I've been using DB Browser and SQLite files from Kaggle.com and I think it's helpful in the sense that it's a single file which maintains the schema. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149029/how-can-i-export-salesforce-data-from-all-salesforce-objects-into-1-single-sqli

Answer (score 0):

Currently standard reporting on external objects is not allowed with Lightining connect.
So you may need to develop logic for reporting using vf pages in salesforce.